# Is chipotle halal to eat

Tags: halal-haram, food

I heard that they cook chicken and pork on the same grill, but they cook them separately. Does that mean we cant eat at chipotle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they use the same grill without washing, then it is haram as pork is *najis*. If their chicken is not slaughtered according to Islamic requirements it is *Maytah* (carrion) and is itself haram.

> قل لا أجد في ما أوحي إلي محرما على طاعم يطعمه إلا أن يكون ميتة أو دما مسفوحا أو لحم خنزير فإنه رجس أو فسقا أهل لغير الله به فمن اضطر غير باغ ولا عاد فإن ربك غفور رحيم
>
> Say, “I do not find, in what has been revealed to me, anything (out of the cattle under discussion) prohibited for anyone who eats it, unless it be carrion or blood that pours forth, or flesh of swine - because it is impure - or there be an animal slaughtered sinfully by invoking on it the name of someone other than Allah. However, if anyone is compelled by necessity, neither seeking pleasure nor crossing the limit, then your Lord is Most-Forgiving, Very-Merciful.”
>
> <sup>— [Quran 6:145](http://quran.com/6/145)</sup>

> عن أبي ثعلبة الخشني أنه سأل رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم قال إنا نجاور أهل الكتاب وهم يطبخون في قدورهم الخنزير ويشربون في آنيتهم الخمر فقال رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم إن وجدتم غيرها فكلوا فيها واشربوا وإن لم تجدوا غيرها فارحضوها بالماء وكلوا واشربوا
>
> Abu Tha’labah al-khushani said that he asked the Messenger of Allah(ﷺ):
>
> "We live in the neighbourhood of the People of the Book and they cook in their pots(the flesh of) swine and drink wine in their vessels."
>
> The Messenger of Allah(ﷺ) said: "If you find any other pots, then eat in them and drink. But if you do not find any others, then wash them with water and eat and drink (In them)."
>
> <sup>— [Abu Daud](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/28/104); also recorded by [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/72/14) and [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/34/12) etc.</sup>